# how to connect my hivemq to test application like MQTTX

Tags: mqtt, hivemq

it seems that all the cluster in hivemq need to run under ssl. I have set up the ssl settings in MQTTX, but it turns out to show exception "certificate has expired!".

[image: foo]

i have tried using cluster url and tls url display on hivemq console

[image: bar]

[image: baz]

Comment: Have you checked if the certificate is actually expired (e.g. with openssl s_client) and if so have you contacted hivemq support (assuming this is hosted by hivemq as you've hidden so much of the hostname it's hard to tell)

Comment: Also there shouldn't be a `/mqtt` in the end of the hostname unless you are connecting to MQTT over Websockets.